# Selecting Additional Rows in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, lag

I am trying to create duplicate records here with all the same values except the DaysToGame column (want it to decrease by one) until it reaches another unique DaysToGame value and would restart the process. For example, the resulting dataset would include an additional row with DAYSTOGAME being 25 and LEFTTOSELL being 23 still (everything else held constant) all the way down until DAYSTOGAME 11 where it would restart the process creating a row for DAYSTOGAME 10 with LEFTTOSELL being 21 and so on.

I have tried using a combination of lag and coalesce, but have had no success getting it to work how I want. Have included the query and resulting dataset! Any and all suggestions welcomed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    EVENTNAME,
    B.DEFAULTPRICECODE,
    DATEDIFF(DAY,SALEDATE,EVENTDATE) AS DaysToGame,
    COUNT(PURCHASEPRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY EVENTNAME, B.DEFAULTPRICECODE ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY,SALEDATE,EVENTDATE) ASC) AS LeftToSell
```

```
EVENTNAME DEFAULTPRICECODE     DAYSTOGAME      LEFTTOSELL
21S1211A         C                 26              23
21S1211A         C                 11              21
21S1211A         C                  8              20
21S1211A         C                  1              18
21S1211A         C                  0               8
```

Comment: A Recursive CTE might work if you did some setup first. Or a user defined table function also would allow carrying state and generating data aware rows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, it's just worth setting a better sorting condition when counting LEAD, but you didn't specify all the columns:

```sql
WITH _sample_data AS ( 
    SELECT EVENTNAME, DEFAULTPRICECODE, DAYSTOGAME, LEFTTOSELL, IFNULL(LEAD(DAYSTOGAME) OVER(PARTITION BY EVENTNAME, DEFAULTPRICECODE ORDER BY LEFTTOSELL DESC), 0) AS PRE
      FROM (VALUES 
          ('21S1211A', 'C',   26,     23),
          ('21S1211A', 'C',   11,     21),
          ('21S1211A', 'C',    8,     20),
          ('21S1211A', 'C',    1,     18),
          ('21S1211A', 'C',    0,      8)) t(EVENTNAME, DEFAULTPRICECODE, DAYSTOGAME, LEFTTOSELL)
), _seq AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SEQ4()) AS VAL
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 365))
)
SELECT d.EVENTNAME, d.DEFAULTPRICECODE, d.DAYSTOGAME, d.LEFTTOSELL, IFNULL(d.DAYSTOGAME - (s.VAL - d.PRE), 0) AS new_column
  FROM _sample_data AS d
  LEFT JOIN _seq AS s ON s.val < d.DAYSTOGAME AND s.val >= d.PRE
 ORDER BY d.EVENTNAME, d.DEFAULTPRICECODE, d.LEFTTOSELL DESC, s.VAL;
```

Result:

| EVENTNAME | DEFAULTPRICECODE | DAYSTOGAME | LEFTTOSELL | NEW_COLUMN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 26 |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 25 |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 24 |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 23 |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 22 |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 21 |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 20 |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 19 |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 18 |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 17 |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 16 |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 15 |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 14 |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 13 |
| 21S1211A | C | 26 | 23 | 12 |
| 21S1211A | C | 11 | 21 | 11 |
| 21S1211A | C | 11 | 21 | 10 |
| 21S1211A | C | 11 | 21 | 9 |
| 21S1211A | C | 8 | 20 | 8 |
| 21S1211A | C | 8 | 20 | 7 |
| 21S1211A | C | 8 | 20 | 6 |
| 21S1211A | C | 8 | 20 | 5 |
| 21S1211A | C | 8 | 20 | 4 |
| 21S1211A | C | 8 | 20 | 3 |
| 21S1211A | C | 8 | 20 | 2 |
| 21S1211A | C | 1 | 18 | 0 |
| 21S1211A | C | 0 | 8 | 0 |